# What  does "no-op" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, translation, programming, software

In the Remarks section of a Microsoft [dbset.add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add%28VS.103%29.aspx#remarks) page I read

> Remarks: Note that entities that are already in the context in some other state will have their state set to Added. Add is a ***no-op*** if the entity is already in the context in the Added state.

What is *no-op* used for, and what does it express?  Is it "not operational"?
I checked in several dictionaries but was unable to find it.

Comment: So far as I know, *no-op* is only ever the microprocessor instruction meaning 'do nothing'. Invariably associated with instruction code 0, largely because if a block of memory containing executable code were to fail or not be correctly written in the first place, it would very like end up containing 0's. Doing nothing is the safest option in that case. It's at least quirky, if not downright geeky, for that MS tech writer to use it in the way he has.

Comment: Strangely, I remember hearing this term with regards to _any_ operation or procedure that ends up requiring no action. I wasn't able to find any corroborating evidence, however. It appears that this is a purely technical term used in computing (specifically assembly).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree that it's geeky. Fortunately it's targeted at geeks, the bulk of whom will understand it.

Comment: @Shimmy: Yes indeed. Who but geeks would be poring over *MS Entity Framework 4.1* documentation? To be honest, I'm somewhat surprised that OP couldn't guess the meaning from context. Perhaps he did really, but wanted to check/expand on his tentative understanding.

Comment: @Fumblefingers - kids today with their automatic garbage collected virtual machines have never heard of assembly language....grumble...

Comment: @FumbleFingers I had an impulse, it happens to many geeks :( @Marin lmao...

Comment: Actually, if we're going to get sniffy about this one, I think it's worth pointing out by today's programming standards, you shouldn't even be *told* if a class method does nothing. If the method exists and has a published calling strategy that should be followed. Otherwise you'd have to change the documentation if the class were reimplemented. This does in fact happen often enough, and it's no business of the programmer writing the calling code to know whether or not he can skip making that call just because it doesn't *yet* do anything of significance internally.

Comment: this really should be migrated to SO or some other computer-oriented stackexchange

Comment: @Fumble, here is where Reflector comes in and makes our life more obvious, @Ken, it's just the comments, this itn't a SO thread. or else they should implement a comments-only board... but this board actually belongs right here, so what I mean to say is... oops StackOverflowException was just thrown! should I catch it and continue till there are no characters left and application doomed?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP

Comment: @Ed, I think you're the only one with a resource...

Comment: *No-op* is common enough in technical documentation. It's not quirky or geeky, it's just jargon.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

"No operation", i.e. do nothing.

It comes from the assembly language instruction "noop" on most processors which does nothing for one clock cycle and is used for example in delays.

Comment: In the early days of microprocessors getting into the home, it wasn't uncommon for games to include *no-op* simply to slow things down enough for players to keep up. Business-oriented code rarely needed that kind of thing. It wasn't until games programmers hit the problem that we got 'timer interrupts', so games could play at the same speed regardless of the hardware they ran on.

Comment: Note that on modern processors the NOP instruction takes considerably less than a cycle, and it not useful for delays any more. It does have a use in code that is compiled for debugging, where it serves as a placeholder for code lines that doesn't produce any machine code, so that each line has some code where a breakpoint can be set.

Comment: Becket: I remember programming my own 'snake' game on a 16Kb Sinclair Spectrum. First I had to write my own assembler program for the machine. And there wasn't enough memory, so I had to put my program *and* its variables into 'screen' memory. Little crawling dots all over the top half-inch of display. Ah! - those were the days!

Comment: Actually, I believe that the time wasting NOOP would actually waste 2 machine cycles. One to FETCH the instruction and one to EXECUTE it because that's what uPs do: Fetch and execute.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be vaguely computer-science related. I think it means that "Add" is a **non-operation**. In more words, the "Add" operation does nothing to an object in the "Added" state. Does that answer your question?

Edit: Martin's answer is better.